# Regex that returns all integers in C# "111; 222; 3333" and "213" in a string with alpha

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am extracting all numbers used in an xml file. The numbers are written in following two patterns

```
<Environment Id="11" StringId="8407" DescriptionId="5014" RemoteControlAppStringId="8119; 8118" EnvironmentType="BlueToothBridge" AlternateId="1" XML_NAME_ID="BTBSpeechPlusM" FactoryGainType="LIN18">
  <Offsets />
</Environment>
```

I am using regex:  "\"\d*;\"" and  "\"\d*\"" to extract all numbers.
from the above when i ran Regex  "\"\d*\"" using

```
Regex.Match(myString, "\"\\d*\"")
```

the above line returns 8407, 11,5014 but it is not returning 8119 and 8118

Comment: Of course not. `"8119; 8118"` does not match the “quoted number” regex you are using.

Comment: What are the requirements? Get any digit chunks from inside attribute values? Or from text nodes? Shouldn't you first parse the XML to get the source for your extraction?

Comment: Don't try and parse XML with regex. Properly parse the data as XML and pull out the values from the fields you want.

Comment: Either skip the check for quotes or semi colons - `"\\b\\d+\\b"` (with added word boundary check) - or allow both - `"[\"; ]\\d+[\"; ]"` (and space)

Comment: BTW, don't you need `1`? See [`(?<=="(?:\d+\s*;\s*)*)\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3d%22(%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5cs*%3b%5cs*)*)%5cd%2b&i=%3cEnvironment+Id%3d%2211%22+StringId%3d%228407%22+DescriptionId%3d%225014%22+RemoteControlAppStringId%3d%228119%3b+8118%22+EnvironmentType%3d%22BlueToothBridge%22+AlternateId%3d%221%22+XML_NAME_ID%3d%22BTBSpeechPlusM%22+FactoryGainType%3d%22LIN18%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cOffsets+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fEnvironment%3e).

Answer (score 3):

Your regex will fail to match 8119; 8118 because your pattern is finding quoted numbers.
try with

```
\b\d+\b
```

\b specify that \d+ will match only in word boundary. So LIN**18** will not match.

Answer (score 1):

Depening on whether you can assume that the provided input is valid XML, you could use the following regular expression:[<sup>1</sup>](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%3b+%3f%5cd%2b%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22%5cd%2b%3b+%3f)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)&i=%3cEnvironment+Id%3d%2211%22+StringId%3d%228407%22+DescriptionId%3d%225014%22+RemoteControlAppStringId%3d%228119%3b+8118%22+EnvironmentType%3d%22BlueToothBridge%22+AlternateId%3d%221%22+XML_NAME_ID%3d%22BTBSpeechPlusM%22+FactoryGainType%3d%22LIN18%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cOffsets+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fEnvironment%3e)

```
Regex.match(myString, "(?<=\")\\d+(?=\")|(?<=\")\\d+(?=; ?\\d+\")|(?<=\"\\d+; ?)\\d+(?=\")" )
```

The main idea behind this is that it takes the three possible situations into account:

- "[number]"
- "[number]; [other_number]" (With or without a space before [other_number])
- "[other_number]; [number]" (With or without a space before [number])

There are two new concepts I included in the regular expression:[<sup>2</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Positive lookahead: (?=[regex])
- Positive lookbehind: (?<=[regex])

These concepts allow the regular expression to check if something specific is before or after it, without putting it in the match.

This regular expression could easily be optimised, but this is meant as an example of a basic approach.

One good tip for developing a regular expression like this is to use a tool (online or offline) to test your regular expression. The tool I used was [.NET Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Comment: You haven't correctly escaped all of your backslashes.  Also that regular expression does not find any matches.

Comment: @juharr Fixed, I messed up in copying it from the Regex tester.
[Link to it actually working](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%3b+%3f%5cd%2b%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22%5cd%2b%3b+%3f)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)&i=%3cEnvironment+Id%3d%2211%22+StringId%3d%228407%22+DescriptionId%3d%225014%22+RemoteControlAppStringId%3d%228119%3b+8118%22+EnvironmentType%3d%22BlueToothBridge%22+AlternateId%3d%221%22+XML_NAME_ID%3d%22BTBSpeechPlusM%22+FactoryGainType%3d%22LIN18%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cOffsets+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fEnvironment%3e)

Comment: I just tested your update and it doesn't match 8119 or 8118.

Comment: Have you tested using Regex.match or the linked .NET regex tester? In the .NET regex tester it actually works.

Comment: I tested in C# and then in .Net Regex Tester.  Both failed.

Comment: In the .NET Regex tester you need to unescape the \ and " characters, as in the already provided [link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%3b+%3f%5cd%2b%22)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%22%5cd%2b%3b+%3f)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%22)&i=%3cEnvironment+Id%3d%2211%22+StringId%3d%228407%22+DescriptionId%3d%225014%22+RemoteControlAppStringId%3d%228119%3b+8118%22+EnvironmentType%3d%22BlueToothBridge%22+AlternateId%3d%221%22+XML_NAME_ID%3d%22BTBSpeechPlusM%22+FactoryGainType%3d%22LIN18%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cOffsets+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fEnvironment%3e).

Comment: OK I figured out the issue was that I had copy and pasted the xml and it put a newline after the `;` before I reformatted and your regular expression relies on the numbers being separated by exactly a semicolon and a space and nothing else.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is true, although the space can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As @poke stated in the comment, it's because your regex doesn't match the string. Change your regex to capture specific matches and account for the possibility of the ';'.

Something like below should probably do the trick.

EDIT: `(\b\d+\b)|(\b\d+[;*]\d+\b)`

[image: Regex Results]

Comment: That regular expression will not give the results in your image.